# Easy expression, I’m stuck here

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

This is an expression obtained for resolving a circuit.
I tried for 1 hour now and I’m close but I’m doing something wrong.

I’m trying to find detA. (details under the photo)

I’m new to this so be kind with me :)

[image: Here it is:]

***detA where A is the first matrice***

$((1/x)+(1/y))*((1/y)+(1/z))$

I came up with this:
$(1/R1*R2)+(1/R1*R3)+(1/R2^2)+(1/R2*R3)-(-1/R2)^2 =$
$(1/R1)((1/R2)+(1/R3)) + (1/R2*R3)$

(**note, maybe the parentheses around fractions are useless**)
There are some similarities, it can be random.

Comment: The first and second matrix aren't the same. Do you understand the relationship between them?

Comment: @JoBe which matrices are you talking about?

Comment: I only see two in the photo. (okay, vectors are matrices, but it is clear what I meant)

Comment: Yeah they aren’t the same but the second is the inverse of the first, so what’s your point? I simply asked how they came up with the second one and people solved everything. I messed up in two parts, especially in the LCM (shame on me lol).

Comment: Well, the only conclusion one could draw from your _original_ question was that you were asking how to manipulate $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$ to get $\frac{a(b+c)}{a+b+c}$, and that's what my initial comment was about.

Comment: That’s what the question is about, now the question is more general but the answers solved my doubts on everything. (i answered you first question, why we still here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that

$$AV=J \implies V=A^{-1}J$$

and

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\
c & d \end{pmatrix}\implies A^{-1}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}d & -b \\
-c & a \end{pmatrix}$$

with

$$\det (A)=\left(\frac1{R_1}+\frac1{R_2}\right)\left(\frac1{R_2}+\frac1{R_3}\right)-\frac1{R_2^2}=\frac1{R_1R_2}+\frac1{R_2R_3}+\frac1{R_3R_1}=\frac{R_1+R_2+R_3}{R_1R_2R_3}$$

Comment: Question edited to be clearer, sorry

Comment: @neilpare2 I've added the derivation for $\det(A)$.

Comment: Oh my god i did the LCM wrong... Shame on me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @neilpare2 You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Your arrow is incorrect.  The equation shows $Ax=b$ where $x$ is the vector of $V(1)$ and $V(2)$, and $b$ is the vector of $J_1$ and $J_2$.  The next line shows $x=A^{-1} b$.

To get the inverse of a 2x2 matrix, negate the off diagonals, switch the diagonals, and divide by the determinant.  Presumably, the matrix they show would be equivalent to this.

Comment: Yeah, the next steps are not a problem, I’m not stuck with the general problem I’m stuck with that expression in particular. If the arrow in the photo is incorrect ignore that sorry.

Comment: Question edited